# get MAE and RMSE

Tags: python, data-science, svd

get MAE and RMSE

do have tried like this

```
movies = pd.read_csv('ml-20m/movies.csv')
ratings = pd.read_csv('ml-20m/ratings.csv')
df = pd.merge(movies, ratings, on='movieId', how='inner')
reader = Reader(rating_scale=(0.5, 5))
data = Dataset.load_from_df(df[['userId', 'title', 'rating']], reader)
trainSet, testSet = train_test_split(data, test_size=.25, random_state=0)
algo = SVD(random_state=0)
algo.fit(trainSet)
predictions = algo.test(testSet)

def MAE(predictions):
        return accuracy.mae(predictions, verbose=False)
def RMSE(predictions):
        return accuracy.rmse(predictions, verbose=False)
    
print("RMSE: ", RMSE(predictions))
print("MAE: ", MAE(predictions))
```

and get error

"Singleton array array(<surprise.dataset.DatasetAutoFolds object at 0x000001BD67B62490>,
dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection."